# input text box does not updated properly for click event button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which the cancel button is not working. I cannot figure out why, when the cancel button is hit, it does not render properly. The expected behavior is when the user hit cancel it would just rollback and hide the admin window. See the jsfiddle below. 
Thanks for all the help

https://jsfiddle.net/launeric/y188v9bg/#&togetherjs=HrxmjAojcq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2017 by AH0HA (http://jsbin.com/hoqerih/6/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="udacity_catclicker_ben_admin_mod">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
<style id="jsbin-css">
img {
    max-width:256px;
    max-height:256px;;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="cat-list"></ul>
    <div id="cat">
        <h2 id="cat-name"></h2>
        <div id="cat-count"></div>
        <img id="cat-img" src="" alt="cute cat">
        <br><button id="cat-admin-button-init" type="button">admin</button></br>
    </div>


    <div id="CatAdminDiv" style="display:none;">
      <br>catName<input type="text" id="adminCatName" value="XXXXXX"></br>  
      <br>catURL<input type="text" id="adminCatURL" value="zzzzzz"></br>
      <br>catCnt<input type="text" id="adminCatCnt" value="999"></br>
      <br><button id="cat-admin-button-save" type="button">save</button></br>
      <br><button id="cat-admin-button-cancel" type="button">cancel</button></br>
   </div> 

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script id="jsbin-javascript">

/* ======= Model ======= */

var model = {
    currentCat: null,


    cats: [
        {
            clickCount : 0,
            name : 'Tabby',
            imgSrc : 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/33358/cat-fold-view-grey-fur.jpg'
        },
        {
            clickCount : 0,
            name : 'Tiger',
            imgSrc : 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/54632/cat-animal-eyes-grey-54632.jpeg',
        },
        {
            clickCount : 0,
            name : 'Scaredy',
            imgSrc : 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zAWnDj_hEeE/UjWq6heqF-I/AAAAAAAAB_8/iThTIziz7VA/s1600/cat.jpg',

        },
        {
            clickCount : 0,
            name : 'Shadow',
          imgSrc : 'http://ravenclan.yolasite.com/resources/Dawnfleck.jpg',

        },
        {
            clickCount : 0,
            name : 'Sleepy',
          imgSrc : 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aBSzB6qxisQ/0.jpg',
            //imgSrc : 'img/9648464288_2516b35537_z.jpg',
            //imgAttribution : 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/onesharp/9648464288'
        }
    ]


};


/* ======= Octopus ======= */

var octopus = {

    init: function() {
        // set our current cat to the first one in the list
        model.currentCat = model.cats[0];

        // tell our views to initialize
        catListView.init();
        catView.init();
    },


    adminInit: function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('CatAdminDiv');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }    



    }, 

    adminCancel: function(){

      this.adminInit();
      catView.render();

    },

    adminSave: function() {

      var x = document.getElementById('cat-name');
      var y = document.getElementById("adminCatName");
      x.textContent = y.value;


    },


    getCurrentCat: function() {
        return model.currentCat;
    },

    getCats: function() {
        return model.cats;
    },

    // set the currently-selected cat to the object passed in
    setCurrentCat: function(cat) {
        model.currentCat = cat;
    },

    // increments the counter for the currently-selected cat
    incrementCounter: function() {
        model.currentCat.clickCount++;
        catView.render();
    }
};


/* ======= View ======= */

var catView = {

    init: function() {
        // store pointers to our DOM elements for easy access later
        this.catElem = document.getElementById('cat');
        this.catNameElem = document.getElementById('cat-name');
        this.catImageElem = document.getElementById('cat-img');
        this.countElem = document.getElementById('cat-count');

        // on click, increment the current cat's counter
        this.catImageElem.addEventListener('click', function(){
            octopus.incrementCounter();
        });



        //admin begin

        this.catAdminButtonInit = document.getElementById('cat-admin-button-init');
        this.catAdminButtonCancel = document.getElementById('cat-admin-button-cancel');
        this.catAdminButtonSave = document.getElementById('cat-admin-button-save');

        this.AdminCatName = document.getElementById('AdminCatName');
        this.AdminCatURL = document.getElementById('AdminCatURL');
        this.AdminCatCnt = document.getElementById('AdminCatCnt');   

        this.AdminCatDiv = document.getElementById('CatAdminDiv');      

        this.catAdminButtonInit.addEventListener('click', function(){
            octopus.adminInit();
        });



        this.catAdminButtonSave.addEventListener('click', function(){
            octopus.adminSave();
        });

        this.catAdminButtonCancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
            octopus.adminCancel();
        });

        //this.catAdminButtonCancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //    octopus.adminCancel();
        //});

        //admin end

        // render this view (update the DOM elements with the right values)
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        // update the DOM elements with values from the current cat
        var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
        this.countElem.textContent = currentCat.clickCount;
        this.catNameElem.textContent = currentCat.name;
        this.catImageElem.src = currentCat.imgSrc;
        this.catNameElem.textContent = currentCat.name;
        this.admincatName = document.getElementById("adminCatName");
        this.admincatName.setAttribute("value", currentCat.name);

        //document.getElementById("adminCatURL").setAttribute("value", currentCat.imgSrc);
        //document.getElementById("adminCatCnt").setAttribute("value", currentCat.clickCount);

      //var x = document.getElementById('AdminCatName');
   // x.setAttribute("value",currentCat.name );

       //x.value = 'xxx';//currentCat.name;
        //var x2 = document.getElementById('adminCatName');
        //x2.value=model.currentCat.name;
    },
  /*
  renderAdmin: function(){
    var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
    //this.AdminCatName.value = currentCat.name;
    var x = document.getElementById('AdminCatName')
    x.setAttribute("value",currentCat.name );
  }
  */

}

var catListView = {

    init: function() {
        // store the DOM element for easy access later
        this.catListElem = document.getElementById('cat-list');

        // render this view (update the DOM elements with the right values)
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var cat, elem, i;
        // get the cats we'll be rendering from the octopus
        var cats = octopus.getCats();

        // empty the cat list
        this.catListElem.innerHTML = '';

        // loop over the cats
        for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
            // this is the cat we're currently looping over
            cat = cats[i];

            // make a new cat list item and set its text
            elem = document.createElement('li');
            elem.textContent = cat.name;

            // on click, setCurrentCat and render the catView
            // (this uses our closure-in-a-loop trick to connect the value
            //  of the cat variable to the click event function)
            elem.addEventListener('click', (function(catCopy) {
                return function() {
                    octopus.setCurrentCat(catCopy);
                    catView.render();
                };
            })(cat));

            // finally, add the element to the list
            this.catListElem.appendChild(elem);
        }
    }
};

// make it go!
octopus.init();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error in console.

Comment: The given code is working fine at my side, you should clear your cache and refresh your page.

Comment: When I modify the catName in the admin box and then click another cat. Then in this instance the catName does not updated. The last catName is still there..